# AChartEngine Legend Icon Size

Tags: android, achartengine

I've looked for an answer throughout stackoverflow, through achartengine's XYMultipleSeriesRenderer documentation and I think it's time to ask this question.

The icons in my legend are tiny. And there is no function to make them larger. I tried setting the legend height, fitting the legend, setting different text sizes for the legend, and a myriad of other combinations. Is there a way to change the icon size?

Here is an image: [image: tiny icons].

If you look really closely, there is a small line with a dot for both items in the legend.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too. I've solved it by just hiding the legend

```
mRenderer.setShowLegend(false);
```

and added into my `.xml-File` below my chart my legend:

**graph.xml:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/chart"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/legend"
    android:layout_below="@+id/chart"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="-.- Correct"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:text="-.- Total"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark/>

</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```